# Hyper-V and WSL2 networks do not communicate

Tags: networking, hyper-v, wsl2

I have a Windows 10 Pro (version 20H2) computer with the following situation:
[image]

The Host, the Hyper-V VMs and WSL2 all have Internet access, they all can communicate each other but wsl2 and the VMs cannot (the red arrows).

My problem is that I cannot ping or ssh wsl2 from a VM and vice versa.

The Hyper-V VMs use the "Default Switch" vNet: 172.29.96.1, netmask: 255.255.240.0, conn type Internal

WSL2 uses "WSL" vNet: 172.23.240.1, netmask: 255.255.240.0, conn type: Internal

There is a third vNet, named "nat", I can see using "ipconfig" but that is not listed in Hyper-V virtual switch manager: 172.25.128.1, netmask 255.255.240.0, conn type: ?

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a solution.

Basically all I need is to set up a port forwarding.

Have a look at here: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150

Answer (score 2):

I pretty much discovered this by chance but it works on my machine.  I am running Raspberry Pi Desktop in a Hyper-V virtual maching on Windows 10 22H2

1. Create a RPi desktop in hyper-v      note mine loops in RPi
   install unless I select skip update.    After the install, edit
   Hyper-v VM settings and set network adaptor to "Default Switch."  You can then open terminal and sudo apt upgrade sudo apt install
2. Start and connect to VM
3. Enable SSH -- For RPi Desktop you can do this in preferences ->
   RPi    Configuration
4. Find the ipaddress (ifconfig in VM command
   line)
5. Ping the IP address from PowerShell on Windows.

Should ping and work

My primary purpose is to exchange files with the VM.  For that I use WinSCP and it all works.  This is all on the same machine.  I am unable to reach it from a different machine on my network.  I just run multiple instances of WinSCP and/or WSL2 Linux terminal and/or PowerShell

Apparently Windows recognizes the IP address as that of the VM and diverts traffic but only on the same machine.

Only a work around not a full solution but I hope it helps someone.